# What do those abbreviations mean in Diablo 2?

Tags: terminology, diablo-ii

After Diablo 3 gets delayed further and further I recently started playing Diablo II online again after aaages. *Thanks reddit ;p*

Since I never was deep into multiplayer in D2 I have now some problems to understand what people say. Here's a list of abbreviations I don't understand so far:

- ED
- MF
- SoJ
- ft or FT
- ISO
- SC
- HC
- cube/cubing
- Ammy
- torch
- wp
- eth
- e-bugged
- 1/49/69/190 Alma Negra
- 1-4os "some armor name"
- fcr
- fhr
- vit
- dex
- En
- SR
- RS
- Decrep
- Blizz
- BlizzBaller
- MeteOrb
- FRW

I think I'll soon add more when I see them.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- ED - Enhanced Damage or Enhanced Defense
- MF - Magic Find
- SoJ - Stone of Jordan
- ft or FT - For Trade (the opposite of ISO, below)
- ISO - In Search Of (what people say when they want to trade for something)
- SC - Softcore
- HC - Hardcore
- cube/cubing - Use of the Horadric Cube
- Ammy - Slang for Amulet
- torch - Hellfire Torch
- wp - Waypoint
- eth - Ethereal
- e-bugged - A bug where ethereal body armor has the ethereal defense bonus on it applied twice when sockets are added to it via the Horadric Cube recipe.
- 1/49/69/190 Alma Negra - A [shield](http://www.diablo2guide.com/database/unique-items/alma-negra-id551.php).  The numbers that come before it reference certain stats on it, since the numbers of certain attributes fall within a certain range.  For example, [here](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?802165-Auction-748-def-ETHEREAL-Alma-Negra) is some guy wanting to trade an Alma Negra, and he describes his stats on it, in words.

  > +2 skills, 203% enhanced defense (748 total defense), 40% enhanced damage, 56% bonus to attack rating

  In that example, his is 2/40/56/203.
- 1-4os - OS = Open Sockets
- fcr - Faster Cast Rate
- fhr - Faster Hit Recovery
- vit - Vitality
- dex - Dexterity
- En - Energy
- SR - Summon Resist
- RS - Raise Skeleton
- Decrep - Decrepify
- Blizz - Blizzard
- BlizzBaller - A sorceress who primarily uses a combination of Blizzard and Fireball
- MeteOrb - A sorceress who primarily uses a combination of Meteor and Frost Orb
- FRW - Faster Run/Walk

Source: way too much Diablo 2, supplemented by http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Abbreviations_and_Acronyms and [http://www.diablowiki.com/Glossary_(Diablo_II)](http://www.diablowiki.com/Glossary_%28Diablo_II%29)

Now that you know the definitions, you can look them up pretty easy I think.  It would be too much to explain each of them in detail here.

Comment: its probably a bad thing I can still remember most, if not all of the acronyms without looking it up

Comment: /sigh ok I won't add more to my question since everything else can be found in a link I was too dumb to stumble upon

Comment: those links, while nice, contain waaaay too many useless acronyms to just read through, but they are great references.  Just from a quick glance, the second is more useful than the first.

Comment: oh and btw: Blizzballer is Blizzard and Fireball, not Orb ;)

Comment: Good catch, will edit that in.

Comment: Could you make this a bullet list instead, so people won't need to scroll horizontally?

Comment: So just to be clear, `1/49/69/190` would mean *"+1 skills, 49% enhanced damage, 69% bonus to attack rating, 190% enhanced defense"*?  Do those numbers always mean the same thing in the same order, or is that just for shields (or are the numbers ordered arbitrarily, and you're just supposed to figure out what they mean)?

Comment: its just for that specific item.  All items usually have their own set of numbers, cta (call to arms) for instance is referred by 3 numbers (for the 3 battle skills).  for example, 2/6/2

Comment: @yx: So is there a listing of what those numbers are for each item?  Or maybe an explanation on how to figure that out?  Explaining just the one doesn't really help, if they're all different.

Comment: @BlueRaja typically the numbers are for the values on the item that are not fixed, but some items have worthless modifiers that players ignore (such as light radius).  The only way to learn it all is through playing and usage, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a few more to Cpt's excellent list:

**Chaos** - Chaos Sanctuary experience farm (if they allow leechers its the best way to level up fast)
 **Baal** - Baal run, also great experience for high levels.
 **Ubers** - Either completing uber Tristram for the torch or farming uber Meph's skeletons for xp (no longer possible to farm uber meph for xp as of patch 1.13)
 **Crush** - classic rush (Rush on classic then promote to expansion, allowing you to bypass the need for killing baal)
 **Rush** - normal rush through all 5 acts.  Typically people who are doing rushes will look for 'staff chars' which means those that have a completed horadric staff ready to go for duriel in act 2.  This saves the time of having to gather the components of making the staff.

There are also some abbreviations for commonly used items/runewords:
 **hoto** - heart of the oak
 **hoz** - Herald of Zakarum
 **tals** - typically refers to tal rasha's rainment set for the sorceress (tals ammy, tals armor, etc)
 **Anni** (typically followed by its stats) - Annihilius, the unique small charm dropped by Diablo clone on certain servers where a # of SOJs have been sold.  i.e. 20/20/10 anni is considered 'perfect' with 20 stats, 20 resist all, and 10% more experience.  Sometimes people just post the first 2 numbers.
 **Torch**  - Hellfire Torch.  Typically followed by stats as well.  20/15 sorceress, for example. Means 20 to all stats 15 to all resists sorceress torch.  sometimes they're abbreviated by the class: storch, ptorch, etc.

Comment: Would you also need Kalims Questitem for A3?

Comment: @F.S. no,all you have to is kill the council, but the rushee has to be within a certain distance when the council dies (they can stay dead on the screen if they are killed and still get the quest).  There is another glitch to get around baal, since he requires you to have completed the ancients quest.  However, only 1 party member (who hasn't done the baal quest yet), has to be there when baal dies.  All the other rushers can wait back in town and still complete the difficulty.

Comment: There's a good glitch rush explanation here: http://newd2event.net/index.php?id=methods/Glitch_Rush_Guide  The reason why the crush exists is so they don't have to glitch baal, but its much harder to rush on classic since there's no runewords.